# Establishing reverse SSH-tunnels via systemd

Tags: systemd, ssh-tunneling

I am currently porting all my crontab configs into systemd-services, i.e. creating units for tasks that needs to autostart on my computers.

One of these units is giving me a headache. I called it "uplink.service", it's purpose is to call a script that builds a reverse ssh tunnel to my server and establishes that. This is the unit I created:

```
[Unit]
Description = SSH-Uplink
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /bin/bash /root/script/uplink.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

This is the script the unit points to:

```
ssh -fNC -R XXXX:localhost:22 user@ip -pXXXX -i ~/script/id_rsa
touch /tmp/uplinkonline
```

As you can see, for debugging this script tries to make a new file called uplinkonline in /tmp. This works; the file is created after starting the service, so the script itself is successfully called.

And this is the output of systemctl after trying to start it:

```
uplink.service - SSH-Uplink
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uplink.service; disabled; 
vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 07 10:44:01 loki systemd[1]: Started SSH-Uplink.
```

The script itself works while starting it manually or calling it by startup via crontab. But somehow systemd seems to expect a different behaviour and exits, without starting the SSH connection. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: More to this problem: It seems that systemd starts the script, but exits it right away - so, for a short moment the connection ist functional. How can I tell systemd that this process needs to be kept alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script starts `ssh` in background and doesn't stick around, while systemd expects the programs it executes to stay running while the service is up.

All you need to do is tell systemd this is a one-shot service, by configuring it with `Type=oneshot` in the service unit. You might also want to include `RemainAfterExit=yes` so systemd keeps listing the service as "up".

In short, update your service file to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH-Uplink
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/script/uplink.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(Note the usual style for systemd unit files has no spaces around the "="s, so I fixed that too.)

You might want to consider adding an `ExecStop=` command to tear down the SSH tunnel, in order to make `systemctl stop uplink` work as expected.

Comment: Using `Type=forking` is perhaps also a possibility, since `ssh -f` will leave a background process around and it's possible systemd will correctly identify it as the main process for the service once the shell script terminates... You might want to give that a try as well if you think that's interesting.

Comment: Hey Filipe, thanks very much, works like a charm! Can you please explain more what you mean by Type=forking? Will this fork the session everytime the process gets killed?

Comment: Using `Type=forking` might work since then systemd will look for a process left around after the shell script finishes, and `ssh -f` will fork and leave an ssh process around like that. See [this example](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.10.5) from systemd documentation for a more exact description of how `Type=forking` looks for a background process to select as the main process for the service. (Using `Type=oneshot` is also OK in this case, so if you're happy with that, it's definitely fine.)